# Problem in converting .dat file into csv format using pandas, Need to split 1 column into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am facing an issue in converting a .dat extension file into csv file using pandas. I have written the following basic code into google colab:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
KY1801.32m.dat(n/a) - 335449 bytes, last modified: 4/27/2021 - 100% done
Saving KY1801.32m.dat to KY1801.32m (2).dat
dat_file = "KY1801.32m.dat"
with open(dat_file,'r') as file:
  text = file.read()
  print(text)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
with open(dat_file,'r') as file:
  df = pd.DataFrame(file)
  print(df.head())
df["sno","year","month","day","hours","minutes","sec","x","y","z","w"]= df[0].str.split(" " , expand 
= True)
df
```

My issue remains that after using the last line of my code, I am getting an error something like the following:

> > ---------------------------------------------------------------------------   KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> > last)   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
> > in _set_item(self, key, value)    3575         try:    -> 3576
> > loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)    3577         except KeyError:
>
> 8 frames    KeyError: ('sno', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hours',
> 'minutes', 'sec', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'w')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent
> call last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py
> in **init**(self, values,     placement, ndim)
> 129         if self._validate_ndim and self.ndim and len(self.mgr_locs) != len(self.values):
> 130             raise ValueError(    --> 131                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
> 132                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"
> 133             )
>
> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 12, placement implies 1

What I want to do is to split my single column 0 in dat file into 12 constituent columns namely: sno, year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds,x,y,z,w  columns based on " " separation. How should I do that? What are the changes needed in my code?

My .dat file can be found here :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SXEB0Dj2PDUYU31RlLYBPG4858Re8M-J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: may be just try `import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("KY1801.32m.dat",sep= " ")` and then clean up the dataframe.

Comment: Right.  That is NOT a "csv" file.  The "c" means "comma", and you have spaces.  So, just tell `pandas` that the separator is a space, as @simpleApp correctly suggests, and you should achieve happiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.dat is creating confusion here, in this case, it's a file with space delimited.
so just put the separator = " "

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("KY1801.32m.dat",sep= " ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but how come .dat format files can be read with pd.read_csv() method?

Comment: csv term itself has been used mostly for delimited files, it happens to be that comma is frontier. even for excel, they say create csv and default is comma but the user can put any delimited value he/she wants. If this has helped, accept/upvote the response. Thx

Comment: Thanks a lot, @simpleApp . I have tried to upvote but it shows I need at least 15 reputation points. Thanks a lot again

Comment: glad that it helped. Thx